# Installing nvcc

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Is there any way to install only the nvcc compiler without installing cuda toolkit?

I want this because I want to compile the cuda program  just for syntax check.
Please suggest if there are any other ways for cuda syntax checking

Comment: you could install the toolkit on one machine, then just copy `nvcc` from the CUDA `bin` directory

Comment: @m.s.: That won't work. nvcc isn't a compiler - there are a number of other executable components (and include files) that would be required to be able to actually compile code for syntax checking. I don't really think this is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

As far I as know, the smallest level of installation granularity in current CUDA distributions is the entire toolkit. There is no way to just install nvcc (and in reality that implies installing a number of binary components beyond the compiler driver, plus all the toolchain header files).